# Add a link from launched Area51 proposals to the live site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, site-proposal, live-phase

I visited [Web Applications](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57?phase=beta) which says that the site is "**Launched!**" Why not provide a direct link from that page to the [live site](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I've just been confused by this, as the link is "below the fold" on my monitor. Could this link also be added to the "this site has launched" box at the top of the right hand sidebar? (to put this a different way, is there any reason why the big, visible, friendly "this site launched" message /doesn't/ link to the site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We added back the "Visit the site now!" link. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Ememett - thanks very much! (Why was it ever taken away?)

Comment: @Mark actually it was a bug...during private beta we only show the link if you committed to the proposal, and we were using that same logic once the site exited public beta

Comment: @David - Aha, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The icon to the left is a link to the live site.

[image]

Comment: Though you're right, keeping the "Visit the site now!" link would make it more obvious.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that. I looked for ages before posting the question because I didn't want someone to show me that I'd missed it... =:-) So, great, correct answer but I can't accept the answer (click the tick) because I think this still needs to be solved. It is too easy to miss.