# Can we have a link to the Area51 proposal on beta sites?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, beta-phase

I'd like the reverse of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69636/add-a-link-from-launched-area51-proposals-to-the-live-site). Just a handy link to look at what was voted on or off topic in the definition phase while participating in any given beta. That is, of course if the result of the definition phase should influence a beta. The point of a definition phase, otherwise, escapes me :)

I spend  lot of effort at work. I also spend a lot of effort answering questions. Please help enhance my small blocks of 'fun time' by adding a convenient link :)

This may be a duplicate, I wasn't quite sure how to search for it.

Comment: While I know in Gaming we discussed on the site that being able to quickly access the proposal would be handy, I don't know of any specific question yet. I'll give a look-see.

Comment: I think this is a great idea - let's do everything to get the new sites off the ground!

Comment: Is there any way to find any site's proposal (including launched sites)? Because I wanted to find the proposal of [`Ask Patent`](http://patents.stackexchange.com/) but [couldn't find it](http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=patent).

Answer (score 7):

I think this has been completed now.

[image]