# Area 51 link in a Stack Exchange site should link to the proposal for that site

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange

Could the "Area 51" link in the footer of the site link to the proposal for said site, rather than to the Area 51 home page? Perhaps just when the site is in public/private beta?

I've had a quick look through the FAQ on [scifi.stackexchange.com](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) and couldn't see a back-link there, hence suggesting that the Area 51 link in the footer might be a good place to put one. This would be useful as the stats page (in this instance http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4451/science-fiction-fantasy) which shows how the site is doing is something that some users of Stack Exchange sites could find useful. Whilst the statistics (questions per day, etc.) are shown on the homepage of each Stack Exchange site, *how they represent how well the site is doing* isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Area51 link in footer didn't change, but now, you have a back link to proposals on all beta sites.

See - [Can we have a link to the Area51 proposal on beta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70396/can-we-have-a-link-to-the-area51-proposal-on-beta-sites)